# Programming in the 1990s - Calculation of program to check if array is ascending

Tags: algorithm, formal-methods

I am working my way through the book: Programming in the 1990s.

I am having difficulty solving exercise 10.12 which asks us to solve:

```
      var f : array of int {0<=#f}
    ; var s : bool
    ; s : s == (Ai,j|0<=i & i<=j & j<#f : f.i<=f.j)
```

I introduce fresh variable n such that

```
    s == (Ai,j|0<=i & i<=j & j<n : f.i<=f.j) & n=#f
```

Which leads me to invariant

```
    I0 : s == (Ai,j|0<=i & i<=j & j<n : f.i<=f.j)
    I1 : 0<=n & n<=#f
```

and guard

```
    B : n != #f
```

The bound function is

```
    t = #f - n
```

and progress is made by the assignment

```
    n:=n+1
```

I know that the solution is very simple, but I always get stuck when trying to maintain the invariance of I0.

Please can somebody show me how to calculate an assignment to maintain the invariance of I0?

Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to translate the meaning of `s` from the language of formal specification to "plain English"?

Comment: Yes, it is a translation into the predicate calculus of the statement: s equivales "array f is ascending".  The notation is of Gries and Schneider's Logical Approach to Discrete Math.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it's "non-descending", not "ascending", but that's the correct translation. Considering your solution that makes progress by assigning to `n`, don't you think that something is missing? Specifically, is it possible to construct a solution that does not assign to `s`?

Comment: Thanks dasblinkenlight, but I disagree with your interpretation of the predicate.  So does Anne Kaldweaij.

Comment: Fortunately, interpretation of mathematical predicates is not a matter of opinion, so it does not matter who else interprets it incorrectly. Here is a counterexample: consider `f={1,1}` which is ordered in non-descending order, and check that according to your specification, `s` should be set to `true` when your program terminates, because for all three valid assignments of `i` and `j`, i.e. `i=0, j=0`, `i=0, j=1`, and `i=1, j=1` `f.i <= f.j` is `true`.

Comment: The predicate is ascending, which is to say that it is non-decreasing.  I did not say that the predicate is increasing.